# Show that $F[x] / (x^2-1) \cong F \times F$ iff $char(F) \neq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, quotient-spaces

Let $F$ be a field. Show that $F[x] / (x^2-1) \cong F \times F$ iff $char(F) \neq 2$.

Here is my work this far: If $char(F) = 2$, then $x^2-1 = (x-1)^2$, and hence $F[x]/(x^2-1)$ has a non-zero element whose square is $0$. But $F \times F$ is a field, so it doesn't have any non-zero elements that square to zero, and hence they are not isomorphic.

Now, I want to show that they are isomorphic if $char(F) \neq 2$. I have tried to construct an isomorphism between the two, but the obvious map ($a + bx + (x^2 -1) \to (a,b)$) does not seem to be a homomorphism. I can't seem to show that it preserves multiplication, and I was hoping it would be possible to show that it preserves multiplication iff $char(F) \neq 2$. How can I prove the second direction of this?

Comment: $F \times F$ is *not* a field - $(1,0)$ is a zero divisor. But you did identify that $F[x]/(x^2-1)$ has a nilpotent element. Can you show that $F \times F$ doesn't?

Comment: @MikeMiller If it did, then there is some $(a,b)$ with $(a,b)(a,b) = (a^2,b^2) = (0,0)$, so $F$ would have at least one nilpotent element, which $F$ can't since it is a field. Is that correct?

Comment: Note that if we take $F = \mathbb{R}$, we get an algebra $\widetilde{\mathbb{C}} := F[x] / (x^2 - 1) \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ often in this context called the *split complex numbers*, a sort of hyperbolic analogue of the complex numbers. Like $\mathbb{C}$ it enjoys a natural conjugation map $u := a + bx + (x^2 - 1) \mapsto \bar{u} := a - bx + (x^2 - 1)$ and a nondegenerate quadratic form $Q(u) := \Re(u\bar{u}) = a^2 - b^2$ multiplicative in that $Q(uv) = Q(u) Q(v)$, but this form is indefinite, so the algebra isn't a normed division algebra, but merely a *composition algebra*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is s special case of Chinese remainder theorem. Send a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ to the pair $(f(-1), f(1))$. CRT states it is surjective.

To see surjectivity avoiding CRT you have to solve a linear algebra problem that requires one to find a polynomial having prescribed values at two given points.
(That is what Lagrange Interpolation Theorem does in Numercal Mathematics)   For it to have a zero at both $+1$ and $-1$ it should be a multiple of $x^2-1$. So the kernel is the ideal generated by $x^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

This map works:
$$\frac{a-b}{2}\cdot x + \frac{a+b}{2}\cdot 1 + (x^2-1)\cdot F[x] \mapsto (a,b)$$

you were close. The map is $\bar f \mapsto ( f(1), f(-1))$